# Increasing speed of parity check matrix

Tags: optimization, matlab, matrix

The code runs fine and takes 100s to complete it for 5 iteration. I need to reduce it to take less time with the same number of iterations.

h = 324 by 648 matrix

The code is that of FFT Belief Propagation for LDPC codes over gf(8).

```
tic

[a2,b2] = size(h); % h is the parity check matrix 324 by 648

%% breaking rn such that each cell contains 3 bits ( soft values from demodulator) as 3 bits will give 1 symbol

z = 3;

mat = repmat(z,1,b2);

sym = mat2cell(rn,1,[mat]); % rn is the received bits that has to be decoded. 

%%Generating the truth table 0 - 255

TT = dec2bin(0:7)=='1';

TTH([1:8],:) = TT([1 2 3 5 4 7 8 6],:);
%% Creating the F matrix (Likelihood)
%% this part is concerned about computing the likelihood of each received bits..

for k = 1:(b2)
    WN = sym{1,k};

    for i = 1:8
        for j = 1:3

            if TTH(i,j)==0
                P(i,j) = 1./(1+exp((2*WN(j))/sig^2));

            else
                P(i,j) = 1./(1+exp((-2*WN(j))/sig^2));
            end
        end
        EN = P(i,:);
        PN(i,:) = prod(EN);
    end
    like{1,k} = PN;
end

F = cell2mat(like);
% size of F = 8 by 648 

[a1,b1] = size(F);

%% whereever there is a non zero value in the h matrix, one cell of F is placed there

for i =1:b2
    for j = 1:a2

        if h(j,i)~=0

            Q_A{j,i} = like{i};

        else Q_A{j,i} = zeros(size(like{i}));

        end
    end
end

Q_Original1 = cell2mat(Q_A);

for itr = 1:iter
[a3,b3] = size(Q_Original1);

Q_1strow(1:8:a3,:) = Q_Original1(1:8:a3,:); % saving the rows that will not be permuted

Q_Original2=Q_Original1;

Q_Original2([1:8:a3],:) = []; % removing the non permuted row from the matrix

[a4,b4]= size(Q_Original2);

%% breaking the matrix and putting it into cells of 7 by 1

for i =1:b4

    for j =1:7:a4

        P_Q{j,i} = Q_Original2(j:j+6,i);
    end
end

% Removing empty array from P_Q

P_QN = P_Q.'; 

P_Qnew = reshape(P_QN(~cellfun(@isempty,P_QN)),b2,[])'; %removing empty cells

%% permuting the each cell according to its position with respect to the H matrix
%% suppose H (j,i) = 2, it will be permuted once. the order of the permutation is found in matrix indx
indx = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
extension = [1 2 4 3 6 7 5]
% h matrix will have values within the extension matrix
% suppose h = 5, permutation order will be 6
for i = 1:b2

    for j=1:a2
        W = P_Qnew{j,i};

        x0 = h(j,i);

        if x0 ==0
            Q_permute{j,i} = W;

        else
            [x2,x3] = find(extension'==x0);
            Q_permute{j,i} = circshift(W, indx(x2,x3));
        end
    end
end

Q_per=cell2mat(Q_permute);

%Removing rows of zeroes from Q_1strow

Q_1stroww = Q_1strow(any(Q_1strow,2),:); 

[p1,p2] = size(Q_1strow);
p3 = p1 -a2;

%% here the unpermuted rows are inserted back by using the function Insertrow from mathswork

permuted_Q = insertrows(Q_per,Q_1stroww, [0:7:p3]); 

%% fft method

[a5,b5] = size(permuted_Q);

YN = hadamard(8);

%% hadamard matrix is applied to columns of 7
for i = 1:8:a5
    for j = 1:b5

        PNN = permuted_Q(i:i+7,j);
        %Rearranging the rows such that each row differ by one bits

        PNN1([1:8],:) = PNN([1 2 3 5 4 8 6 7],:);

        %YN=hadamard(8); % Use of Hadamard matrix to compute fft

        F_P(i:i+7,j)= YN*PNN1;
        %F_P(i:i+3,j)= fft(PN);

    end
end

[a6,b6] = size(F_P);
B(1:a6,1:b6) = inf;

for i = 1:a6
    for j=1:b6
        if (F_P(i,j)~=0)
            B(i,j)= j;

        end
    end
end

for i = 1:a6
    for j=1:b6

        AP = find(B(i,:)==j);

        if (length(AP)~=0)

            prodt=1;

            I1= find(B(i,:)~=inf & B(i,:)~=j);

            for i1 = 1:length(I1)
                prodt = prodt.*F_P(i,I1(i1));

            end

            rin(i,j) = prodt;
        end
    end
end

[a7,b7] = size(rin);
% inverse fft using hadamard matrix to obtain matrix R
for i = 1:8:a7
    for j =1:b7

        XN = rin(i:i+7,j);

        R_d = (1/8).*(YN*XN); % inverse of the Fast Hadamard Transform

        R_f([1 2 3 5 4 8 6 7],:) = R_d([1:8],:); % bringing back the values to their original position

        R(i:i+7,j) = R_f;
    end
end

[a8,b8] = size(R);
%saving the unpermuted row

R_1strow(1:8:a8,:) = R(1:8:a8,:);

R_1 = R;
%deleting the unpermuted row from the matrix
R_1([1:8:a8],:)=[];

[a9,b9]=size(R_1);

% putting into cells
for i =1:b9
    for j = 1:7:a9

        R_dper{j,i} = R_1(j:j+6,i);

    end
end

R_dperm = R_dper.';

R_dpermut = reshape(R_dperm(~cellfun(@isempty,R_dperm)),b2,[])';

for i = 1:b2
    for j =1:a2

        Z = R_dpermut{j,i};
        x0 = h(j,i);

        if x0==0
            R_dpermuted{j,i} = Z;

        else 
            [x2,x3] = find(extension'==x0);

            R_dpermuted{j,i} = circshift(Z,-indx(x2,x3));
        end
    end
end

R_depermuted = cell2mat(R_dpermuted);

R_1stroww = R_1strow(any(R_1strow,2),:);

depermuted_R = insertrows(R_depermuted,R_1stroww,[0:7:p3]);

%% Vertical Step

% Breaking the depermuted_R matrix into 4 matrices

[a10,b10] = size(depermuted_R);

R1 = depermuted_R(1:8:a10,:);
R2 = depermuted_R(2:8:a10,:);
R3 = depermuted_R(3:8:a10,:);
R4 = depermuted_R(4:8:a10,:);
R5 = depermuted_R(5:8:a10,:);
R6 = depermuted_R(6:8:a10,:);
R7 = depermuted_R(7:8:a10,:);
R8 = depermuted_R(8:8:a10,:);

C(1:a2,1:b2) = inf;

for i = 1:a2
    for j = 1:b2

        if (h(i,j)~=0)

            C(i,j)=i;
        end
    end
end

for i = 1:b2 %colums

    for j = 1:a2 % rows

        P = find(C(:,i)==j);

        if (length(P)~=0)

            prod1 = 1;
            prod2 = 1;
            prod3 = 1;
            prod4 = 1;
            prod5 = 1;
            prod6 = 1;
            prod7 = 1;
            prod8 = 1;

            I3 = find(C(:,i)~=inf & C(:,i)~=j);

            for i3 = 1:length(I3)

                prod1 = prod1.*R1(I3(i3),i);
                prod2 = prod2.*R2(I3(i3),i);
                prod3 = prod3.*R3(I3(i3),i);
                prod4 = prod4.*R4(I3(i3),i);
                prod5 = prod5.*R5(I3(i3),i);
                prod6 = prod6.*R6(I3(i3),i);
                prod7 = prod7.*R7(I3(i3),i);
                prod8 = prod8.*R8(I3(i3),i);

            end

            const1 = prod1.*F(1,i);
            const2 = prod2.*F(2,i);
            const3 = prod3.*F(3,i);
            const4 = prod4.*F(4,i);
            const5 = prod5.*F(5,i);
            const6 = prod6.*F(6,i);
            const7 = prod7.*F(7,i);
            const8 = prod8.*F(8,i);

            constbeta = 1/(const1 + const2 + const3 + const4 + const5 + const6 + const7 + const8);

            new_Q1(j,i) = constbeta*const1;
            new_Q2(j,i) = constbeta*const2;
            new_Q3(j,i) = constbeta*const3;
            new_Q4(j,i) = constbeta*const4;
            new_Q5(j,i) = constbeta*const5;
            new_Q6(j,i) = constbeta*const6;
            new_Q7(j,i) = constbeta*const7;
            new_Q8(j,i) = constbeta*const8;

        end
    end
end

for i = 1:a2
    AN = new_Q1(i,:);
    BN = new_Q2(i,:);
    CN = new_Q3(i,:);
    DN = new_Q4(i,:);
    EN = new_Q5(i,:);
    FN = new_Q6(i,:);
    GN = new_Q7(i,:);
    HN = new_Q8(i,:);

    L{i,:} = vertcat(AN,BN,CN,DN,EN,FN,GN,HN);

end

Q_Original1 = cell2mat(L);

% Pseudo Posterior Probabilities

for i =1:b2
    for j = 1:a2

        CK = find(C(:,i)==j);

        if (length(CK)~=0)

            prdt1 = 1;
            prdt2 = 1;
            prdt3 = 1;
            prdt4 = 1;
            prdt5 = 1;
            prdt6 = 1;
            prdt7 = 1;
            prdt8 = 1;

            I4 = find(C(:,i)~=inf);

            for i4 = 1:length(I4)

                prdt1 = prdt1.*R1(I4(i4),i);
                prdt2 = prdt2.*R2(I4(i4),i);
                prdt3 = prdt3.*R3(I4(i4),i);
                prdt4 = prdt4.*R4(I4(i4),i);
                prdt5 = prdt5.*R5(I4(i4),i);
                prdt6 = prdt6.*R6(I4(i4),i);
                prdt7 = prdt7.*R7(I4(i4),i);
                prdt8 = prdt8.*R8(I4(i4),i);

            end

            cnst1 = prdt1.*F(1,i);
            cnst2 = prdt2.*F(2,i);
            cnst3 = prdt3.*F(3,i);
            cnst4 = prdt4.*F(4,i);
            cnst5 = prdt5.*F(5,i);
            cnst6 = prdt6.*F(6,i);
            cnst7 = prdt7.*F(7,i);
            cnst8 = prdt8.*F(8,i);

            cnstbeta = 1 / (cnst1 + cnst2 + cnst3 +cnst4 +cnst5 +cnst6 +cnst7 +cnst8);

        end
    end

    Y1(i)= cnstbeta*cnst1;
    Y2(i)= cnstbeta*cnst2;
    Y3(i)= cnstbeta*cnst3;
    Y4(i)= cnstbeta*cnst4;
    Y5(i)= cnstbeta*cnst5;
    Y6(i)= cnstbeta*cnst6;
    Y7(i)= cnstbeta*cnst7;
    Y8(i)= cnstbeta*cnst8;
end

Q_dash = vertcat(Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5,Y6,Y7,Y8);

end

[a11,b11] = max(Q_dash);

for i = 1:length(b11)

    if b11(i)==1
        decoded_bits(i) = 0;
    elseif b11(i) ==2
        decoded_bits(i)=1;
    elseif b11(i) ==3
        decoded_bits(i)=2;
    elseif b11(i)==4
        decoded_bits(i)=4;
    elseif b11(i)==5
        decoded_bits(i)=3;
    elseif b11(i)==6
        decoded_bits(i)=6;
    elseif b11(i)==7
        decoded_bits(i)=7;
    elseif b11(i)==8
        decoded_bits(i)=5;
    end
end
toc
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about what the code does, it will be much easier to help you that way.

Comment: Use `profile` to find which part is the slowest first.